# creating a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am running following query but it is showing me an error..

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 18

```
 DELIMITER //
    create procedure usp_ItemAdd(
    p_itemname varchar(50),
    p_company varchar(50),
    p_model varchar(50),
    p_unit varchar(10),
    p_photo varchar(12),
    p_color varchar(50),
    p_size varchar(50),
    p_weight varchar(20),
    p_stock varchar(20)
)
begin
  insert into item_tbl(
item_name,company,model_no,unit,photo,color,size,weight,stock
)
values(
  p_itemname,p_company,p_model,p_unit,p_photo,p_color,p_size,p_weight,p_stock
  )
end //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It seems that you missed the right ')' before `end`...

Comment: You need a delimiter at the end of the procedure.

Please check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Please check updated my query but same error showing.

Comment: You are missing the `;` at the end of the `insert` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `delimiter` and finish `insert` statement with `;`

```
delimiter $$
create procedure usp_ItemAdd(
    p_itemname varchar(50),
    p_company varchar(50),
    p_model varchar(50),
    p_unit varchar(10),
    p_photo varchar(12),
    p_color varchar(50),
    p_size varchar(50),
    p_weight varchar(20),
    p_stock varchar(20)
)
begin
    insert into item_tbl(
    item_name,company,model_no,unit,photo,color,size,weight,stock
)
values(
    p_itemname,p_company,p_model,p_unit,p_photo,p_color,p_size,p_weight,p_stock
);
end $$
delimiter ;
```